# Understanding Program Size - ATMega328P

Tags: c, avr-gcc

I am interested in finding out the memory usage of my code running on an ATMega328P (16 MHz) using the `avr-size` utility bundled with WinAVR 20100110. Using the Makefile included in the distribution I obtained the following memory usage for the code below:

```
#include <avr/io.h>
#include <stdint.h>

int main(void)
{  
    while(1)
    { }
    return 0;
}
```

The console output is:

```
make all 

-------- begin --------
avr-gcc (WinAVR 20100110) 4.3.3
Copyright (C) 2008 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
This is free software; see the source for copying conditions.  There is NO
warranty; not even for MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.


Compiling C: src/main.c
avr-gcc -c -mmcu=atmega328p -I. -gdwarf-2 -DF_CPU=16000000UL -Os -funsigned-char -funsigned-bitfields -fpack-struct -fshort-enums -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -Wa,-adhlns=./src/main.lst  -std=gnu99 -MMD -MP -MF .dep/main.o.d src/main.c -o src/main.o 

Linking: src/main.elf
avr-gcc -mmcu=atmega328p -I. -gdwarf-2 -DF_CPU=16000000UL -Os -funsigned-char -funsigned-bitfields -fpack-struct -fshort-enums -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -Wa,-adhlns=src/main.o  -std=gnu99 -MMD -MP -MF .dep/main.elf.d src/main.o --output src/main.elf -Wl,-Map=./src/main.map,--cref     -lm

Creating load file for Flash: src/main.hex
avr-objcopy -O ihex -R .eeprom -R .fuse -R .lock -R .signature src/main.elf src/main.hex

Creating load file for EEPROM: src/main.eep
avr-objcopy -j .eeprom --set-section-flags=.eeprom="alloc,load" \
    --change-section-lma .eeprom=0 --no-change-warnings -O ihex src/main.elf src/main.eep || exit 0

Creating Extended Listing: src/main.lss
avr-objdump -h -S -z src/main.elf > src/main.lss

Creating Symbol Table: src/main.sym
avr-nm -n src/main.elf > src/main.sym

Size after:
AVR Memory Usage
----------------
Device: atmega328p

Program:     134 bytes (0.4% Full)
(.text + .data + .bootloader)

Data:          0 bytes (0.0% Full)
(.data + .bss + .noinit)



-------- end --------
```

When I run the same code with the `while()` construct removed the program size is reported to be `138 bytes`. Same happens if I comment out both while() and the return statement. How can the program size increase when I remove a loop construct? The Makefile uses the `-S` optimizer for gcc. Does it have something to do with it?

Comment: Since the while doesn't do anything it may be optimized away. But I doubt it is that simple. Have you looked at the code produced in the two situations? I suspect the run-time environment requires an infinite loop for all apps and if you don;t supply one, the compiler will. Now I have to research it myself. I have an Uno plugged in here somewhere....

Comment: My first guess would be that avr has to generate the exit-code for leaving main() when you omit the loop.

Comment: Compile with -s and diff the two output files, to see *what* the difference is.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The kind-of short answer is **the compiler is saving you space by noticing that the while loop is never returning**.  Knowing that the function never returns means that it can skip sending the return value up the stack, which saves you two instructions, which is four bytes on AVR.

The longer answer and more useful information:

Assembly is essentially always compiled down to the same size for each instruction (on architectures with only one size of instruction, of which AVR is almost - most  operations are 2 bytes).   That means that more assembly code means a larger program.

You can see the reason that the one with the `while()` loop is larger if you examine the difference in the assembly listing files.

Listing for the main.c with the while loop:

```
  ......
  14                    .file 1 "main.c"
   1:main.c        **** #include <avr/io.h>
   2:main.c        **** #include <stdint.h>
   3:main.c        **** 
   4:main.c        **** int main(void)
   5:main.c        **** {  
  15                    .loc 1 5 0
  16                /* prologue: function */
  17                /* frame size = 0 */
  18                /* stack size = 0 */
  19                .L__stack_usage = 0
  20                .L2:
  21 0000 00C0              rjmp .L2
  22                .LFE0:
  50                .Letext0:
  ..... (Symbol table follows)
```

And the main.c code without the while loop:

```
  ...... (everything the same up to here)
  14                    .file 1 "main.c"
   1:main.c        **** #include <avr/io.h>
   2:main.c        **** #include <stdint.h>
   3:main.c        **** 
   4:main.c        **** int main(void)
   5:main.c        **** {  
  15                    .loc 1 5 0
  16                /* prologue: function */
  17                /* frame size = 0 */
  18                /* stack size = 0 */
  19                .L__stack_usage = 0
   6:main.c        ****     return 0;
   7:main.c        **** }
  20                    .loc 1 7 0
  21 0000 80E0              ldi r24,0
  22 0002 90E0              ldi r25,0
  23 0004 0895              ret
  24                .LFE0:
  52                .Letext0:
  ..... (Symbol table follows)
```

You can see in the lines marked 20-24 in the non-while loop code, that it is loading up a couple registers and then calling the `ret` subroutine return instruction.  In the while loop one, they skip that, because the compiler realizes that in lines 20-21, nothing is going to get out of that loop.

Comment: I did compile the code to assembly using the gcc -S flag and realized the same thing and was about to answer my own question. Thanks for your explanation!